# Deploying Dynamics CRM SDK updates

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

We currently have Dynamics 2013 on premises deployed (version 6.0.3.106).

We have some plugins that reference the SDK but had an issue with a bug in that version of the SDK. This is fixed in 6.1.15 and so we have downloaded this version and want to use it instead.

My question is, how do I go about adding the latest version of Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll to the Dynamics server? Do they manually have to go in a certain folder or is there some automated install?

Thanks

Comment: Cant you just re-deploy the project after you amend all the project references?

Comment: But they will only deploy my custom assemblies, not the versions of the SDK it references.

Comment: I will investigate this, but i compiled a project for 2015 with 2013 dlls then i replaced them with the 2015. If the deployment works as you state all the plugins should have failed for the different version of the .net framework used to compile the dlls.

Comment: @Draiden resolving the references is not the issue, I want the server to be using the latest version of the SDK. Should I be only doing this from SP/Rollups?